# Uploading different versions (python 2.7 vs 3.5) to PyPI

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have a package I'm uploading to PyPI with two different versions of the code: one for Python 2.7 and one for Python 3.5.

What is the standard for uploading this to PyPI? Do I use two separate `setup.py` files?

When users run `pip install mypackage` will it automatically download the correct version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;DR: add `python_requires` on `setup.py`. Use [twine](https://github.com/pypa/twine) to upload the package to PyPI.

Like IPython, its 6.0.0+ support Python 3.3+ only and the 5.x still support Python 2.x. If you install it using `pip` >= 9.0.1, `pip install ipython` will select latest 5.x for Python 2 and latest 6.x for Python 3.

## Modify `setup.py`

First, you need set [Requires-Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/#requires-python) ([PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers)) meta-data in `setup.py`, by putting the `python_requires` argument on `setup()` function.

For example, the following is the `setup.py` for the Python 2.7 version:

```
setup(
    name='some-package',
    version='2.3.3',
    ...,
    python_requires='==2.7.*'
)
```

For Python 3.5+, just change it to `python_requires='>=3.5'`.

Of course, two packages must have different version numbers. otherwise PyPI will reject one.

You can use two separate `setup.py` files to do this,
or just use one file and set `python_requires` argument dynamically.

## Upload to PyPI

`python setup.py sdist upload` seems to not upload package meta-data (which contains *Requires-Python*) to PyPI.

I found the easiest way to do it correctly is using [twine](https://github.com/pypa/twine).

> 1. Create some distributions in the normal way:
>
>    ```
>    $ python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
>    ```
> 2. Register your project (if necessary)
> 3. Upload with twine
>
>    ```
>    $ twine upload dist/*
>    ```

Repeat step 1 & 3 for both Python 2 and 3 version.

Comment: This approach will automatically detect which version of the package I am using depending the python version pip is tied to? Or do I need to specify the package version number?

Comment: Automatically, for pip 9.0.1 or above. Check the source of `https://pypi.python.org/simple/<package-name>/` page, if everything goes right, links should be like `<a data-requires-python=">=3.5" href=…`. pip use this information to select version.